# Saving Data in for loop with octave

Tags: loops, save, octave

I've a tiny problem with octave.

I want to simulate something and therefore I need a loop but unfortunately my data are not saved by octave. I tried some possibilities for solving this problem but I can't find any solution for me.

This is the code of my file:

```
%------ input from the user --------
%-----------------------------------

at=1;                  % acq. time in s

nu=300;               % Resonance frequency in Hz

scantime=1.1;          % time for a scan, >at in s

T1=(0.1*at:at/10:120*at)';                 % in s

T2=T1;                      % in s

noisestd=1;                 % noise std

expt = (at+scantime);                % experiment time



%-------RATIOS----------


T2T1ratio=(0.01:0.01:12)';                        %T2T1 ratio


att1ratio=at*1./(T1);                                %acquisition time by T1


%----------CALL CALCSPEC.M--------------
%----------------------------------------



for T1idx = (1:(rows(T1)))'
    for T2T1ratioidx = (1:rows(T2T1ratio))'
        for att1ratioidx = (1:rows(att1ratio))'
            spectrum = [s2n, peakwidth] = calcspec(at,nu,scantime,T1,T2,noisestd,expt);
            m={T1idx,T2T1ratioidx,att1ratioidx,s2n,peakwidth}
        endfor
    endfor
endfor
```

And this is the code of my .m file:

```
function [s2n, peakwidth] = calcspec(at,nu,scantime,T1,T2,noisestd,expt);



%---- calculating input vars -----------------
%---------------------------------------------

ns=round(expt/scantime);                % nr. of scans

Fs = 4*nu;                              % Sampling frequency (>=2*nu by Nyquist)

t = ((0:(at*Fs-1))/Fs)';                   % Time vector

fn=2^nextpow2(at*Fs);                   % number of points for the FT (must be power of 2)

res = Fs/fn;                            % spectral resolution (bins in the fft)

freq=0:res:(Fs-res);                    % frequency axis

fid=exp(-i*2*pi*nu.*t).*exp(-t./T2);    % generation of "clean" FID

fid=ns*fid'/max(fid);                   % normalization of FID 

for scan=1:ns
    noisyfid = fid+=noisestd*randn(1,res+1)';       % noisy fid
endfor




% FOURIER TRANSFORM 
% -----------------

sig = fft(fid, fn);                                                   % FT of clean spec

noisysig = fft(noisyfid, fn);                                        % Fourier Transform of noisy spec


%-------Calc S2N ----------
%---------------------

s2n = var(real(sig))/var(real(noisysig));


% DETERMINE FULL WIDTH AT HALF MAXIMUM + INTENSITY
%----------------------------------------------------

peakwidth = fwhm(real(sig));

intensity = max(real(sig));
```

As you can see (hopefully) I have tried to save my data in a cell array but after calculation just one value for s2n and peakwidth are saved.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: It's probably because you transposed the variables in your for loops - there is no iteration there eg. 
for T1idx = (1:(rows(T1)))'
sets T1idx once as a large vector and iterates through for loop only once

Answer (score 0):

Although you are looping you are not using the indices at all in your calculations inside the loop. You probably need to do something like that:

```
[s2n(%appropriate index%), peakwidth(%appropriate index%)] = calcspec(at,nu,scantime,T1(T2T1ratioidx),T2(T2T1ratioidx),noisestd,expt);
% same applies for m calculation
```

Also, you have two `=` signs on the same line, not sure what the end result will be, but it's likely to not be what you expect:

```
spectrum = [s2n, peakwidth] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

many thx for your answers!

the two `=` signs i made because otherwise my octave was giving me the message that there are some variables were undefined, so i tried this.

now i tried to change everything which is wrong but i still don't understand that thing with the indices. now i tried to use the indices `T1idx` in my code so that i get now:

```
    for T1idx = (1:(rows(T1)))
    for T2T1ratioidx = (1:rows(T2T1ratio))
        for att1ratioidx = (1:rows(att1ratio))
            [sig(T1idx),noisysig(T1idx)] = calcspec(at,nu,scantime,T1,T2,noisestd,expt);
            s2n = sig/noisysig;
            peakwidth = fwhm(real(sig));
            m={s2n,peakwidth};
        endfor
    endfor
endfor
```

but now i get the message: `A(I) = X: X must have the same size as I` and i haven't any good idea to get "better" indices......

i just want to get, at the end, a cell array with the following structure:

```
T1idx   T2T1ratioidx   att1ratioidx       s2n         peakwidth
1          1                1          a value         a value
2          .                .              .              .
3          .                .              .              .
4
.
```

it's clear what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think everything was fine before, except that transposition. To save everything you might do something like

```
for T1idx = (1:(rows(T1)))
    for T2T1ratioidx = (1:rows(T2T1ratio))
        for att1ratioidx = (1:rows(att1ratio))
            spectrum = [s2n, peakwidth] = calcspec(at,nu,scantime,T1,T2,noisestd,expt);
            m=[m; {T1idx,T2T1ratioidx,att1ratioidx,s2n,peakwidth}]
        endfor
    endfor
endfor
```

EDIT: And to make m look like you want it:

```
i = 1;
m = [];
for T1idx = (1:(rows(T1)))
    for T2T1ratioidx = (1:rows(T2T1ratio))
        for att1ratioidx = (1:rows(att1ratio))
            spectrum = [s2n, peakwidth] = calcspec(at,nu,scantime,T1,T2,noisestd,expt);
            m(i,:)=[T1idx,T2T1ratioidx,att1ratioidx,s2n,peakwidth];
            i = i + 1;
        endfor
    endfor
endfor
m
```

Comment: thx for that! but it seems that it not working well :-( i tried to understand this part of the code: 'm=[m; {T1idx,T2T1ratioidx,att1ratioidx,s2n,peakwidth}]' why did u use the square brackets and use one more time 'm'? sry, for my stupid questions :-(

Comment: This simply appends {T1idx,T2T1ratioidx,att1ratioidx,s2n,peakwidth} at the back of m array since new m = [old m; something new]. Loops should be working, if the above is not how you want your data to be stored then have a look at the edit.

Comment: many, many thx for your explanations! i think the next days i'll getting forward with my work :-)